# trying to get nomachine working on ubuntu

Tags: remote-desktop, nx, freenx

I need to connect to my ubuntu machine (15.04) from windows 10 machine. 
I've installed nomachine server on ubuntu and i can see that it's running the NX protocol on port 4000 as per the server GUI

From the windows machine, when I try to connect, I get error 138 connection timed out.

Tests:

I can ssh using putty from windows 10 to ubuntu machine no problems. 
But I can't seem to get nomachine working.

Any tips would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I've run the following command to see if port 4000 is open:

```
 netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

And among other things, this is what I get back:

```
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

EDIT 2

I removed and reinstalled like so:

```
me@devbox:~$ sudo dpkg --purge nomachine && sudo rm -rf /usr/NX /etc/NX .nx
[sudo] password for me: 
(Reading database ... 496028 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nomachine (5.1.26-1) ...
NX> 702 Starting uninstall at: Tue Jul 19 09:32:57 2016.
NX> 702 Uninstalling: nxserver version: 5.1.26.
NX> 702 Uninstall log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxuninstall.log.
NX> 702 Saving configuration file to: /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg.backup.
NX> 702 Saving passwords DB to: /usr/NX/etc/passwords.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving users DB to: /usr/NX/etc/users.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving administrators DB to: /usr/NX/etc/administrators.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving profiles DB to: /usr/NX/etc/profiles.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving guests DB to: /usr/NX/etc/guests.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving hosts DB to: /usr/NX/etc/hosts.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving nodes DB to: /usr/NX/etc/nodes.db.backup.
NX> 702 Saving groups DB to: /usr/NX/etc/groups.db.backup.
NX> 702 Uninstalling: nxnode version: 5.1.26.
NX> 702 Uninstall log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxuninstall.log.
NX> 702 Saving configuration file to: /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.backup.
NX> 702 Deleting user: nx from the system.
NX> 702 Uninstalling: nxplayer version: 5.1.26.
NX> 702 Uninstall log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxuninstall.log.
NX> 702 Uninstalling: nxclient version: 5.1.26.
NX> 702 Uninstall log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxuninstall.log.
NX> 702 Uninstall completed at: Tue Jul 19 09:33:52 2016.
Purging configuration files for nomachine (5.1.26-1) ...
me@devbox:~$ sudo dpkg -i /home/me/Downloads/nomachine_5.1.26_1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package nomachine.
(Reading database ... 496015 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nomachine_5.1.26_1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nomachine (5.1.26-1) ...
Setting up nomachine (5.1.26-1) ...
NX> 700 Starting install at: Tue Jul 19 09:42:52 2016.
NX> 700 Installing: nxclient version: 5.1.26.
NX> 700 Using installation profile: Ubuntu.
NX> 700 Install log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxinstall.log.
NX> 700 Compiling the USB module.
NX> 700 Installing: nxplayer version: 5.1.26.
NX> 700 Using installation profile: Ubuntu.
NX> 700 Install log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxinstall.log.
NX> 700 To connect the remote printer to the local desktop,
NX> 700 the user account must be a member of the CUPS System Group: lpadmin.
NX> 700 Installing: nxnode version: 5.1.26.
NX> 700 Using installation profile: Ubuntu.
NX> 700 Install log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxinstall.log.
NX> 700 Creating configuration in: /usr/NX/etc/node.cfg.
NX> 700 Installing: nxserver version: 5.1.26.
NX> 700 Using installation profile: Ubuntu.
NX> 700 Install log is: /usr/NX/var/log/nxinstall.log.
NX> 700 Creating configuration in: /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg.
NX> 700 Install completed at: Tue Jul 19 09:43:33 2016.
NX> 700 NoMachine was configured to run the following services:
NX> 700 NX service on port: 4000
me@devbox:~$
```

Then I launched the GUI for the service and made sure it's running.

Now on my windows machine, I retry connecting but it's still failing.

When you say it could be firewall, should I check on the Ubuntu side or on the windows side?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you changed something in nxserver configuration. Try to remove NoMachine completely from system `sudo dpkg --purge nomachine && sudo rm -rf /usr/NX /etc/NX .nx` and reinstall from scratch.

Could be a problem with firewall. But it's weird I use NoMachine regularly on Ubuntu and don't have such problems. It may be a good idea to look on their forums.

Comment: Please see my EDIT 2

Answer (score 0):

It would be the firewall on the server, check that the ports aren't being blocked.

You could try turning it off, try to connect and then after your test turn it back on.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like firewall issue, can you try enabling port 4000 in the iptables with

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
```

Could be good to enable UDP ports as well.